# How to make my class implement from IMyInterface<T>?

Tags: c++-cli

I want to port the following code from c# to c++/cli:

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<int> { ... }
```

I've tried

```
class ref class MyClass : IEnumerable<int>
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has multiple types of inheritance.  Don't forget to specify it, e.g.:

```
ref class MyClass : public IEnumerable<int>
{ };
```

In C++/CLI, I frequently find myself spelling out the full namespace in interface implementations.  E.g.:

```
ref class MyClass :
    public MyCompany::MyProject::MyComponent::IMyInterface
{ };
```

If your class doesn't actually implement the provided interface, you'll also (of course) get an error.  And you'll want to remove the `^` from the class declaration.  You're inheriting from an interface, not from a GC Handle to an instance of that interface.

Comment: Yeah, it was System::Collections::Generic instead of System::Collections, but anyway I'll give you the points as what you said is useful for anyone searching about the topic.

Comment: Whatever the problem was, this isn't it. In C++/CLI, `public` is the only supported inheritance visibility qualifier, and it is also the default one, so `class MyClass : IFoo` and `class MyClass : public IFoo` are precisely equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is exactly what you're trying to compile, you have an extra `class` there. It should be just `ref class`, and not `class ref class`. Also, don't forget to translate any C# `using` statements to C++ `using namespace`, i.e.: `using namespace System::Collections::Generic`.